# antd form initialize with a complex multilevel nested object

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

With data being given:

```
formValues = {
  level: {
    test: data1,
    level2: {
      test: data2,
      level3: { 
        test: data3
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I have an Ant Form like this:

```
<Form
    form={form}
    name="demo"
    onFinish={onFinish}
    initialValues={formValues}
>
    <Form.Item label="Sub1" name={['level', 'test']}>
        <Input placeholder="Sub1" />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="Sub2" name={['level.level2', 'test']}>
        <Input placeholder="Sub2" />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="Sub1" name={['level.level2.level3', 'test']}>
        <Input placeholder="Sub1" />
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Maybe someone knows why I can't initiate the third level? Level 1 and Level 2 are being displayed, however level 3 doesn't seems to work.

I can't figure out, how the third level does differ... Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The [antd documentation for Form](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-nest-messages) gives an example of form nesting, but only for the first level.

I couldn't find an example elsewhere that used multiple levels, but I found that adding additional indexes to represent each level does the trick.

Instead of this:

```
<Form.Item label="Sub1" name={['level.level2.level3', 'test']}>
    <Input placeholder="Sub1" />
</Form.Item>
```

Try this:

```
<Form.Item label="Sub1" name={['level', 'level2', 'level3', 'test']}>
    <Input placeholder="Sub1" />
</Form.Item>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-antd-4-17-2-forked-xreh2?file=/index.js:425-912)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to spread your nested initial value as below

```
<Form initialValue={alreadyData ? {...alreadyData} : {}>
.
.
.
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you`re trying to do, but in my tests if you want to reach "data3" this is the correct path.

`formValues.level.level2.level3` will return `{"test": "data3"}`

I saw that your third `<Form.Item>` element is almost identical to your first form element, this might have caused confusion? Anyways I threw togeather a CodeSandbox,

https://codesandbox.io/s/qgzb7

Comment: There is no confusion :) The third form item just doesn't populate :(